# $\operatorname{Prob}\limits_{x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_q^*}[\gcd(xy \bmod q, pq)>1: \gcd(x,pq)=\gcd(y,pq)=1]=?$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

For given two distinct odd primes $p$ and $q$, how to count the probability
$$\operatorname{Prob}\limits_{x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_q^*}[\gcd(xy\bmod q, pq)>1: \gcd(x,pq)=\gcd(y,pq)=1]=\, ?$$

Comment: Are we to assume that p and q are primes?

Comment: The question makes no sense unless you make some assumptions on $x$ and $y$. Perhaps the intended assumptions would be they are uniformly and independently chosen from between 1 and $pq$, inclusive. Have you tried any experiments, e.g., letting $p=3$, $q=5$, computing the probability, looking for patterns?

Comment: @Foo, it says in the statement that $p,q$ are distinct odd primes.